# Is it possible for interest to = principal for all and each installments?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, finance, actuarial-science

In practice, there are two main amortization methods used by and large for retail mortgages:

1. The classical amortization formula where all installments have the same value, however the interest % and principal % vary, with the former decreasing over time. 
     $$A = P \frac{r(1+r)^n}{(1+r)^n - 1}$$
2. Decreasing installments with principal equal for all months and a decreasing interest component

Take for example the case of the following mortgage loan:

> P = 250,000 
> r = 8.00% 
> n = 360 months 
> A = 1834.41 
> o.w interest = 1.667.67 (91% of first installment) 
> o.w principal 167.7 (9% of first installment)

Is it possible to devise a method to fix the interest part (50%) = the principal part (50%) for each installment, when reimbursing a bank loan - but to still reach the interest rate applied (for ex 8%)?

Given principal would be paid in an accelerated fashion in this scenario - what would be the impact on:

- The monthly installment factor A? (would it increase?)
- The duration of time for the loan would increase? (i.e a 30 year old mortgage would reach 60 years in such a system?)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are repaying the loan at the rate $r$, where $r$ is the interest rate, so that the repayment and interest rate payment are the same. However, the maturity of the loan will be infinite assuming $r<1$, as you never pay back the loan exactly. The instalment is $2rP_t$, where $P_t$ is the principal that is left at time $t$. This is decreasing over time. The interest payment and debt repayment are both $rP_t$

To add some details, the time $t$ repayment is

$$P_0\times(1-r)^tr$$

Total repayments up to $t$ are

$$P_0\left[r+(1-r)r+(1-r)^2r+(1-r)^3r+\right]=P_0r \frac{1-(1-r)^t}{r}=P_0(1-(1-r)^t)$$

So the principal left at $t$ is

$$P_0(1-r)^t$$

This approaches 0 as $t$ tends to infinity but never reaches it exactly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the quick answer, I wish I was as smart as you. Could you please help me understand the intuition behind this result: this is because the constraint of interest=principal leads to very small values at the end of the series? Also, is it possible to keep n=360 months and to raise the monthly installment instead (with interest=principal) or not?

Comment: @oculator I added some details. Yes as the principal shrinks as the interest rate payments get smaller and smaller. The the repayment must also get smaller and smaller so the loan is never paid back exactly.

Comment: You cannot have $n=360$ with this rule. However, you could do some approximate solution like follow the rule for the first 359 months and then pay back what is left in month 360. Then the rule would be satisfied except for the last month.

Comment: You sir are amazing! The last workaround is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @oculator If you are willing to have unequal periods between installments then you can have equal proportions of interest and principal for all installments. But the period between the last two installments would have to be several years if the interest rate is only 8 percent; you have to wait long enough for the accumulated interest to equal the principal remaining after the next-to-last payment.